# Is there a script or binding that I can use to make a text box read only?

Tags: widget, google-app-maker

I need to use a text box to display the information but it needs to be read only so that the user can't edit the information in the box.

I have looked at other questions similar to this and tried their way but nothing has worked out.

Comment: There is a setting, towards the top left hand near the widget menu button there is a style variant dropdown. Click on this and there should be a read only option.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa the only option is View Only If Disabled and it didn't do anything. Am i supposed to put a code or a script with it?

Comment: I apologize, I did not have App Maker in front of me so I was working off memory. But yes you are correct, it will be a two step process, set the style variant to 'view only if disabled' and then uncheck your enabled setting for your textbox.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution from [@Markus Malessa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5322594/markus-malessa) in the comment above, you can also just use a label instead of a text box to accomplish the same thing. I have a custom label style set up that I can use to make the text in the label look like the text in any surrounding text boxes. Using the label instead means that the user doesn't get the disabled pointer when they mouse over it.